# Adding a key/value pair to an object in VTL (for API Gateway)

Tags: aws-api-gateway, vtl

I am writing a mapping template for an AWS API Gateway integration response. I would like to add a key/value pair to the JSON object returned my Lambda function.

My function returns some JSON like this:

```
{
  "id": "1234",
  "name": "Foo Barstein"
}
```

I would like the template to output something like this:

```
{
  "id": "1234",
  "name": "Foo Barstein",
  "href": "https://example.tld/thingy/1234"
}
```

And my mapping template looks like this:

```
#set($thingy = $input.json('$'))
#set($thingy.href = "https://example.tld/thingy/$thingy.id")

$thingy
```

However, my template outputs the unmodified `$thingy`, without the `href` I have tried to add.

I've read the [VTL user guide](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.5/user-guide.html#set), but to no avail.

Comment: It is so junk, that AWS adopted VTL to deal with json objects or for any type of mapping.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this has worked for me:

```
#set($body = $input.path('$'))
#set($body.href = "https://example.tld/thingy/$body.id")
$input.json('$')
```

Comment: this is the answer - does exactly what the original question asked for

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to achieve this but you can workaround it:

```
## Mapping template
#set($body = $input.body)
#set($id = $input.json('$.id'))
{
  "custom": {
    "href" : "https://example.tld/thingy/$id"
  },
  "body": $body
}
```

And then merge all the keys in AWS.Lambda (if you use Lambda):

```
## Lambda handler
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  const requestParams = Object.assign({}, event.body, event.custom);
  // ... function code
}
```

And `requestParams` will be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Following could do the trick. Beware, untested!

```
{
  #set($payload = $util.parseJson($input.json('$')))
  #set($body = "{
    #foreach ($mapEntry in $payload.entrySet())
      ""$mapEntry.key"": ""$mapEntry.value"",
    #end
    ""href"": ""$payload.id""
  }")
  $body
}
```